# SQL Server Connection Failed with Linux Mint + SQL Server 2008 R2 using any client

Tags: linux, linux-mint, openssl, sql

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server 2008 R2 with SP4 database, however, I got this error and I have tried some solutions that I found here, but none works for me.

PS. I do not know exactly how to understand this error, but I sure that is something about SSL+LINUX

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
>
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
>
> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.
>
> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol

I know the error is:

> SSL Handshake failed with OpenSSL error

My openssl version:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
built on: Mon Apr 20 11:53:50 2020 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/openssl-P_ODHM/openssl-1.1.1f=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_TLS_SECURITY_LEVEL=2 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

I have also tried to change my `openssl.cnf`:

1. Add this line at the beginning

   ```
    openssl_conf = default_conf
   ```
2. Add these lines at the end

   ```
    [ default_conf ]
    ssl_conf = ssl_sect
    [ssl_sect]
    system_default = ssl_default_sect

    [ssl_default_sect]
    MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
    CipherString = DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1
   ```

But I am still getting this error.

PS: I am using Azure Data Studio, VSCode or whenever client like .Net I still getting the error
PS: It is important to say that I could connect in the past in the same database, however, I need to format my PC to a new fresh mint installation

Comment: If you're receiving the same error from different clients, then logically the problem should be at the database end. You should verify that the database supports the TLS version requested by the client. By the current standards, that should be TLS v1.1 or v1.2.

Comment: Tks, but I think is not a problem DB.  I can connect in another PC using Linux mint, and in  the past in the same PC, however, I needed to format my PC to a new fresh mint installation and after that ONLY this PC cant connect

Comment: Okay, have you cross checked the openssl config file from that system? You may have configured it to use an earlier version of TLS, which the database apparently supports.

Comment: This is the problem I do not know how to configure properly, can you help ?

Comment: You can start by examining the `MinProtocol` parameter in the openssl.cnf file. Compare the value of this parameter between the two systems. If the values are the same, do a comparison of the entire file. You can use a diff tool for this, or just do it manually. Once you have identified the difference(s), you can apply the settings from the old system to the new system - be sure to back up the config file first.

Comment: Also, please note that we're going about this backwards. Ideally, you'd move from the 2008 version of the database to a current version, so that you can use more modern versions of the TLS protocol (v1.3 is currently being adopted widely). Downgrading to an older version of TLS might resolve your issue, but it also has security ramifications. For example, TLS v1.0 is vulnerable to some specific attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tks all, for who is facing the same issue:
I Just downgrade the SSL to 1.1.1 and it works.

SQL server 2008 r2 SP3 should support 1.1.1g or 1.1.1f.

Below are the instructions to follow:

1. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+t).
2. Fetch the tarball: `wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz`
3. Unpack the tarball `with tar -zxf openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz && cd openssl-1.1.1`
4. Issue the command `./config`.
5. `sudo apt install make gcc`
6. `make`
7. `make test` to check for possible errors.
8. Backup current openssl binary: `sudo mv /usr/bin/openssl ~/tmp`
9. Issue the command `sudo make install`.
10. `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl`
11. Run the command `sudo ldconfig` to update symlinks and rebuild the library cache.

Assuming that there were no errors in executing steps 4 through 10, you should have successfully installed the new version of OpenSSL.

Again, from the terminal issue the command:

```
openssl version
```

Your output should be as follows:

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

source(dif openssl but same approach)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102803/how-to-upgrade-openssl-1-1-0-to-1-1-1-in-ubuntu-18-04